# How to use an array to represent a complex polygon?

Tags: arrays, numpy, polygon

I've converted a Digital Elevation Model (DEM), basically a polygon representing the perimeter of a city, into a list of x and y coordinate values. I am currently using a square np.zeros(x+1,y+1) array to represent the city, put I want to create an array from my x,y values (something along the lines of np.ones) so that the operation I want to carry out can be mapped to the actual shape of the city.

Something along the lines of if x=1, carry out the calculation, if x=0, do not calculate.

```
for j in range(1,J+1):
    for i in range(1,I):
        #internal node equation etc etc#
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you have a complex 1D array where each element is a complex number of the form x + yj?

Comment: The way I imported the data left me with two separate lists for my x and y values, I tried combining them to make an array using 

Array = list(zip(x,y)) 

but that doesn't seem to have done it